# LVM - How to determine if group is active

Tags: lvm

Last time i had troubel with LVM and i found solution. It consisted of activate group through  command:
`vgchange -a y`
But i wonder how to determine if group is activated, `vgdisplay` do not show that information.

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 2):

`vgdisplay -A` only shows active groups. (It's quite literally the first described option in `man vgdisplay`.)

> ```
> -A|--activevolumegroups
>      Only select active VGs. The VG is considered active if
>      at least one of its LVs is active.
> ```

Note that technically, `vgchange -a y` doesn't activate the volume group, but all LVs within the group.

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your answer. Your answer guided me that 'active' is logic volume attribute, and may show it by `lvs` ( fifth letter in Attr). It's a pity `lvdisplay` doesn't show this parameter